# How to create a legend title in a ggplot2 line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am creating a line graph using the ggplot2 package in R.

I cannot upload the data as it is for a study I am conducting for my final year project. So, I can only share the code with you.

This is the code for the APA formatted graph.

```
ggplot(accuracy_data, 
       aes(x = eccentricity, y = accuracy, group= speech_task)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=speech_task)) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("twodash", "dotted", "solid")) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = speech_task)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ duration, labeller=labeller(duration = labels)) +
  labs(x='Eccentricity (degrees of visual angle)', y='Accuracy of responses') +
  theme_apa() +
  theme(text=element_text(family='Times')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks =c(5, 10, 15)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = accuracy - acc_sum$se , ymax = accuracy + acc_sum$se ), width=.1)
```

This produces a graph with a legend without a title, hence I am asking for help in creating a title for the legend.
I have tried a lot of different options however none work. I don't even get an error message. 
These are the codes I have tried so far:

```
legend_title <- "Speech Task"
scale_fill_manual(legend_title,values=c("Conversation", "N-Back", "Silence"))
```

```
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Speech Task"))
```

```
scale_fill_discrete(name = "Speech Task",
                    labels = c("Conversation", "N-Back", "Silence"))
```

```
labs(fill="Speech Task")
```

The following and final code I tried was the only one to produce a change in the graph. However because I have manually changed the point shape as well as line type it caused two legends to be made and only titled the line type legend.

```
labs(linetype= "Speech Task")
```

Please can I have some help :)

Comment: From which package is your `theme_apa`? In case of `jtools` try `jtools::theme_apa(legend.use.title = TRUE)`

Comment: @stefan I do use that package for `theme_apa()`. So, I just tried that and got these error:
Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?

Comment: I guess that this is a different issue. As you provided no data I checked on mtcars and adding `legend.use.title = TRUE` worked for me and added the legend title. However, I dropped the geom_errobar in the last line and also the labeller inside `facet_grid`.

Comment: @stefan I have to include the error bars unfortunately as it needs to be in an APA format. Also, it took me a long time to label the facet grids correctly so need that bit too.
Sorry I didn't share data, I think it would be against the ethical guidelines.

Comment: Don't mean you have to drop your errorbars and labels. (: Was just for checking and making the example a bit more easier. Maybe you could provide an example of your datasets using `dput`.

Comment: ... but first. Have you tried whether `legend.use.title = TRUE` works when you drop the errorbars and/or labeller?

Comment: @stefan Oh I see what you mean, sorry!! I tried removing the error bars and the labeller and it still came up with the same error message.
Sorry I am very new to R and have no idea what you mean by a `dput`

Comment: As your are using two datasets. First. Type `dput(accuracy_data)` into the console and paste the output as code into your question. Second. Type `dput(acc_sum)` into the console and ... In case that your dataset is large simply use `dput(accuracy_data[1:20,)` which for example gives just the first twenty rows of data.

Comment: @stefan Sorry I asked someone at university and the problem was theme_apa() it wasn't allowing the legend title even when I called the true argument. So to get it to work I took it out and manually set parts of the graph so it was APA formatted. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing no data or final results I'm going on a hunch here.

I suspect you need to name shape and fill legends the same. So something along the lines of

```
scale_linetype_manual(name = legend_title, values = c("twodash", "dotted", "solid")) + 
scale_fill_manual(name = legend_title, values = c("Conversation", "N-Back", "Silence")) +
```

Comment: I tried the code and it just seperated the legend so I was left with two and neither had a title.

Comment: @ewest29 can you make a small mock dataset we can play with?

Comment: I tried to create one but when trying to practice with it, it said I have used discrete data instead of a continuous variable.
It don't think it is meant to be hard data to create, the speech task has 3 levels: conversation, n-back and silence, eccentricity has 3 levels: near, mid and far and duration has 3 levels 50, 150, 250. These are all random but should occur the same amount of times each. The only bit which varies and is continuous is accuracy which ranges from 0 to 1.